# Python: Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Tags: python, file, sh, pickle

I am getting a weird error when calling the following:

`spark2-submit --master local --deploy-mode client --queue ${my_queue} mypyfile.py ${arg1} ${arg2}`

I get the error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

The error I found occurs on the following line:

```
with open(file_loc, 'rb') as f:
    rows = pickle.load(f)
```

Why is this happening on a python file? It is within a sh script, but even if I run the spark2-submit command on its own I get the same error.

Comment: What is in previous line?

Comment: You're running a python script with sh?  Do you need a `#!/usr/bin/env python` line?

Comment: I'm running the python script with spark2-submit, but that is within a sh script.

Comment: Can you run your script as `python mypyfile.py` instead of just `mypyfile.py`? Or will that confuse spark2-submit?

Comment: @00 within spark2-submit? I've isolated it down to the pickle load line, but if I run it in the python terminal it works fine

Comment: If it were a Python error, you'd get a `SyntaxError`, not `syntax error`. This is a shell error, thus looking at a line in your Python script is not good enough. Most likely, your Python script is run as a shell command.